# LineSegmentDetector (openCV 3) in javacv

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, javacpp

I would like to use the [LineSegmentDetector of OpenCV 3](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html) in java. Unfortunately it does not seem to be part of the javacpp opencv distribution. What would be the fastest way to use this algorithm im java? The C code is [publicly available](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2012/gjmr-lsd/).

Comment: just use opencv's own/official 3.0 api, not javacv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now available here, which is eventually going to get merged with the master branch:

https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/blob/opencv-3.0/opencv/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_imgproc.java#L2672